# How to trim and split URL string

Tags: javascript, html, url, split

How could I just extract the text **`androiddev`** from the following string in JavaScript?

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/49878b/droidcon_sf_is_11_days_away/
```

I tried trimming it from the back, but I'm still stuck with the front part.

Been stuck at this for a few hours now, would really appreciate any help!

Comment: `String.prototype.trim()` is available in modern browsers.

Comment: @Pointy but is that not only for when there's whitespace on both sides?

Comment: `var value = 'yourstring'.split('/')[4]`

Comment: It trims whitespace off of both sides. If there's no whitespace on one or both sides, nothing happens to that side. *edit* **oh wait** I see. You're trimming non-space stuff. Sorry, never mind.

Comment: The title of the question is misleading: PO actually asks how to get the Sub-string from the string (should it be indeed about Trimming text, then @Pointy gave exact answer). Please correct the question. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell Title of question may include trim, but if you READ the post, it is obvious that this is not the exact method that the OP wan'ts needs. Hope you didn't down vote everyone for understanding what you didn't.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I didn't downvote anyone's answer, I just edited the title. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and fast :)

```
var value = 'yourstring'.split('/')[4]
```

Comment: @isvforall see third comment in question section :)

Comment: It's ok :) Most important that your answer is right too :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/49878b/droidcon_sf_is_11_days_away/"
var name = str.split('/')[4]
console.log(name);// androiddev
```

Comment: This is a good solution in this case where the slashes nicely delimit the desired data. May not be the best solution if data isn't that nicely enclosed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `substr` String function:

```js
 var s = "https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/49878b/droidcon_sf_is_11_days_away/";
 var ss = s.substr(25, 10);
 alert(ss);
```

Where the first argument is what index position to begin extracting at and the second is how many chars. to extract.

Comment: Don't you just hate it when some over zealous Stack Overflow user feels the need to down vote everybody who posts CORRECT answers because they feel that their answer is MORE CORRECT?

Comment: I don't downvote, but I think that strings may have different length

Comment: Yes, of course different strings will have different lengths, but my answer shows how to extract a substring, which is relevant no matter what string you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can just split the whole URL with `/`, but I generally find it safer to break the URL into known parts, then extract information from those.

Here's a sort of sneaky way to do URL parsing in the browser

```
function parseUrl(url) {
  var elem = document.createElement('a');
  elem.href = url;
  return {
    protocol: elem.protocol,
    host:     elem.host,
    hostname: elem.hostname,
    port:     elem.port,
    pathname: elem.pathname,
    hash:     elem.hash
  };
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/49878b/droidcon_sf_is_11_days_away/"
parseUrl(url).pathname.split('/')[2]; // "androiddev"
```

Comment: Why not just `new URL(url)`?